# Populating an entire column with same value returned from a CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am trying to populate a column with the same result value from a resulting CASE statement through the entire `s_date`/`part_no` grouping.

We have tried multiple different routes to get recursion to work for what we're needing, but with no luck.  The calculations are extremely tricky, and we know SQL isn't the best for recursion, so we're trying to find an alternate route to go for the time being to meet the customer needs and time crunch.

```
SELECT
        s_date,
        part_no,
        i_group,
        s_level,
        p_category,
        qty_filled,
        qty_total,
        relief_amt,
        extreme_amt,
        curr_mth_note,
        CASE
            WHEN curr_mth_note IS NOT NULL
                 AND i_group = '1'
                 AND s_level = '80' THEN qty_filled
            ELSE NULL
        END AS g1s1_filled
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                t1.s_date,
                t1.part_no,
                t1.i_group,
                t1.s_level,
                t1.p_category,
                t1.qty_filled,
                t1.qty_total,
                mv.relief_amt,
                mv.extreme_amt,
                mv.curr_mth_note,
            FROM
                multi_table mv,
                t_table t1
            WHERE
                t1.part_no = mv.part_no
                AND mv.part_no = 'xxxx'
                AND t1.s_date = mv.s_date
                AND t1.s_date = '201805'
            GROUP BY
                t1.s_date,
                t1.i_group,
                t1.s_level,
                t1.part_no,
                t1.p_category,
                t1.qty_filled,
                t1.qty_total,
                mv.relief_amt,
                mv.extreme_amt,
                mv.curr_mth_note,
            ORDER BY
                t1.s_date,
                t1.i_group,
                t1.s_level DESC
        )
ORDER BY
    s_date,
    part_no,
    i_group,
    DECODE(s_level, '80', 1, '100', 2, 'Late', 3)
```

The current output for the above looks like this:

[image]

What I'm trying/hoping to get is the entire `g1s1_filled` column to show the same 67 amount where `i_group = '1' and s_level = '80'` for all available date/part combos.

So for that column to show this:

```
G1S1_FILLED
67
67
67
67
67
```

I've researched how to try to use a where instead of when, with no luck. 
 There will be multiple other columns built out like this, to where I can eventually do calculations as well.

Comment: In your example data, only one record meets the criteria of `i_group = '1'` and `s_level = '80'` and it's value is 67 for `g1s_filled`. So I am having trouble seeing the problem.

Comment: @RyanWilson yeah I know, but I'm going to be doing separate calculations for each i_group / s_level combo, that has to build off of the previous totals dependent on what is left in the relief_amt column.  So I'm trying to populate the same value vertically so I can make those calculations work as expected.

Comment: What if there is more than one 1/80 row for an `s_date`/`part_no` combination - how will you choose which of the `qty_filled` values to use? (Or do those four columns form a composite key, so that can't happen?)

Comment: @AlexPoole  That will not happen, as the date/part/group/level combo qtys are already being calculated within the other views, and being pulled into here, so we can use them individually for a report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a window function:

```
    SUM(CASE WHEN curr_mth_note IS NOT NULL AND i_group = '1' AND
                  s_level = '80'
             THEN qty_filled
        END) OVER (PARTITION BY s_date, part_no)  AS g1s1_filled
```

Comment: Thank you so much ... This worked great! I was able to build out the calculations and get the results I was hoping for as well.  I hate when the answers seem so simple and I feel like I've wracked my brain for hours.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a conditional analytic minimum in the `SELECT` clause. I don't have your data, so I will illustrate with a similar query on the `SCOTT.EMP` table - suppose I want to fill `NEWCOL` with the salary of one particular employee. I would do it like this:

```
select empno, ename, sal, job, deptno,
       min(case when empno = 7499 and ename = 'ALLEN' then sal end) over () as newcol
from   scott.emp;

     EMPNO ENAME             SAL JOB           DEPTNO     NEWCOL
---------- ---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH             800 CLERK             20       1600
      7499 ALLEN            1600 SALESMAN          30       1600
      7521 WARD             1250 SALESMAN          30       1600
      7566 JONES            2975 MANAGER           20       1600
      7654 MARTIN           1250 SALESMAN          30       1600
      7698 BLAKE            2850 MANAGER           30       1600
      7782 CLARK            2450 MANAGER           10       1600
      7788 SCOTT            3000 ANALYST           20       1600
      7839 KING             5000 PRESIDENT         10       1600
      7844 TURNER           1500 SALESMAN          30       1600
      7876 ADAMS            1100 CLERK             20       1600
      7900 JAMES             950 CLERK             30       1600
      7902 FORD             3000 ANALYST           20       1600
      7934 MILLER           1300 CLERK             10       1600
```

If (in your problem) there is only one row with the "special" combination of values in `I_GROUP` and `S_LEVEL`, then you can use (conditional, analytic) `MIN` or `MAX` or even `AVG` or `SUM` - they will all be equal to the single value, 67 in your case. If there is more than one such value, then you will need to make a choice: do you want the `MIN`, the `MAX`, the `AVG`, or perhaps something else. In any case, you can still use the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

instead of case statement, write a subquery for it

```
(select qty_filled 
  from t_Table 
  where 
    i_group = '1' and 
    s_level = '80' and
    rownum = 1 
) as g1s1_filled
```

Comment: This only returns the column with a value of 1 in all of them.

Comment: I am not sure about your table relations. you can put your relational constraint on where caluse so that It will return what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `CASE` expression and move your whole query (excepted the `ORDER BY` clause) to a CTE. Then you can self-`JOIN` it to append the relevant `g1s1_filled` to each row.

NB : you have to be careful when defining the self-join conditions ; I provided a suggestion below, you might need to refine it.

Query :

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        s_date,
        part_no,
        i_group,
        s_level,
        p_category,
        qty_filled,
        qty_total,
        relief_amt,
        extreme_amt,
        curr_mth_note
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                t1.s_date,
                t1.part_no,
                t1.i_group,
                t1.s_level,
                t1.p_category,
                t1.qty_filled,
                t1.qty_total,
                mv.relief_amt,
                mv.extreme_amt,
                mv.curr_mth_note,
            FROM
                multi_table mv,
                t_table t1
            WHERE
                t1.part_no = mv.part_no
                AND mv.part_no = 'xxxx'
                AND t1.s_date = mv.s_date
                AND t1.s_date = '201805'
            GROUP BY
                t1.s_date,
                t1.i_group,
                t1.s_level,
                t1.part_no,
                t1.p_category,
                t1.qty_filled,
                t1.qty_total,
                mv.relief_amt,
                mv.extreme_amt,
                mv.curr_mth_note,
            ORDER BY
                t1.s_date,
                t1.i_group,
                t1.s_level DESC
        )
)
SELECT a.*, b.qty_filled as g1s1_filled
FROM 
    cte AS a
    INNER JOIN cte as b 
        ON  b.s_date = a.s_date 
        AND b.part_no = a.part_no 
        AND b.i_group = '1' 
        AND b.s_level = '80'
        AND b.curr_mth_note IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    a.s_date,
    a.part_no,
    a.i_group,
    DECODE(a.s_level, '80', 1, '100', 2, 'Late', 3)
```